# Read JSON object after conversion from CSV format

Tags: python, json, csv

I used csv and json libraries to convert csv file into json file.
csv file is as follow (only one column):

```
document
"[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4}]"
"[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4}]"
"[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4, 'param5': 'value5',  'param6': {'param6-1': 'value6-1', 'param6-2': [value6-2-1, value6-2-2]}}]"
```

json file is as follow (after conversion) :

```
[
    {
        "document": "[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4}]"
    },
    {
        "document": "[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4}]"
    },
    {
        "document": "[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4, 'param5': 'value5',  'param6': {'param6-1': 'value6-1', 'param6-2': [value6-2-1, value6-2-2]}}]"
    }
]
```

the thing is that I supposed to have this results :

```
[
    {
        "document": {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4},
                    {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4},
                    {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': value3, 'param4': value4, 'param5': 'value5',  'param6': {'param6-1': 'value6-1', 'param6-2': [value6-2-1, value6-2-2]}}
    }
]
```

the following code converts from CSV to JSON :

```
def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []

    # read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        # load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        # convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader:
            # add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)

    # convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)


csvFilePath = r'DataCSV.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'DataJSon.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

The questions is : is the conversion done correctly ? in that case, how to interogate complex values ? such as param6-2 ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The data in your `document` column appears to almost be Python formatted data. Your example though is badly formatted, all values should be quoted, for example:

```
document
"[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': 'value3', 'param4': 'value4'}]"
"[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': 'value3', 'param4': 'value4'}]"
"[{'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'param3': 'value3', 'param4': 'value4', 'param5': 'value5',  'param6': {'param6-1': 'value6-1', 'param6-2': ['value6-2-1', 'value6-2-2']}}]"
```

Assuming this is actually the case, then these lines could be converted using `ast.literal_eval()` to read the data back in, and the resulting data converted back to JSON format as follows:

```
import json
import csv
import ast

with open('DataCSV.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f_input, open('DataJSon.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    data = [ast.literal_eval(row['document']) for row in csv_input]
    f_output.write(json.dumps([{'document' : data}], indent=4))
```

This would give you an output `DataJSon.json` file containing:

```
[
    {
        "document": [
            [
                {
                    "param1": "value1",
                    "param2": "value2",
                    "param3": "value3",
                    "param4": "value4"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "param1": "value1",
                    "param2": "value2",
                    "param3": "value3",
                    "param4": "value4"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "param1": "value1",
                    "param2": "value2",
                    "param3": "value3",
                    "param4": "value4",
                    "param5": "value5",
                    "param6": {
                        "param6-1": "value6-1",
                        "param6-2": [
                            "value6-2-1",
                            "value6-2-2"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```